# Usage of "tum" in English speaking countries, other than the UK

Tags: word-usage, contractions

I'm sure I've heard tummy used in American English and the English spoken in commonwealth countries as a sort of euphemism for stomach. I'm not sure so much how common it is to hear it reduced to tum, as in "I ate the pie and now it's in my tum!"

Would that be universally understood in English? How about if I made a construction like tumcandy - would that work in all countries?

Comment: In AE, the use of "tummy" is fairly common, but usually when an adult is speaking to a child, as in, "So, sweetie, your tummy hurts?" or "So, sweetie, do you have a tummy ache?" One adult to another would likely ask, "So, you have a stomach ache?" unless he wanted to give the impression of talking down to, or condescending to, another adult. A doctor would likely say, "So, you have an ache in your belly [or abdomen]?" As for "tum," an adult in speaking to a child might use the even cuter expression "tum tum," meaning tummy/stomach/belly.

Comment: ...(to extend @rhetorician's thought) but, no, 'tumcandy' wouldn't really 'work' in the US. It's obviously candy, but what kind? The stomach doesn't really come up because it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I've never heard the word _tum_ by itself, except for Tums, the brand name of an antacid.

Comment: Children have *tummies* (rarely, *tums*). Adults have ***bellies***.

Comment: Tum is quite common in the UK and you can even call it a 'tum-tum' if you are talking to a child or just being facetious.

Comment: That's interesting @Mitch - I was think of eyecandy as something that makes youe eye hungry but something that makes you stomach hungry doesn't work. What about tumpunch - would that suggest a blow to the stomach in America or not really? It would work in England, especially the North but as someone said, we're two countries separated by the same language!

Comment: Playability: For me, 'tumpunch' by itself is nonsense. But in some sort of context, say, "I tumpunched the guy  who looked at me funny', I'd have the general feeling that the guy got punched, but I'm not sure where (that is, to one AmE speaker, me, 'tum' added on front doesn't mean 'stomach'. If you then went on to explain that it means stomach I'd think "Oh, yes, I guess, but 'tummy' would be the way to say it" (but 'tummy-' would sound very infantile))

Comment: So maybe it works in the UK, but not in the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the search engine of the NY Times found no examples of the word 'tum' being used as an abbreviation for stomach, though plenty for 'tummy' used in that sense.

In Britain, exercises to tone abs and thigh muscles are often known as 'bums and tums' workouts, but googling the term gets hits that are overwhelmingly UK (one Irish). So I would think 'tum' is rarely used outside British English.

Comment: Yes I just checked the Washington Post which has nothing either, where as in the Daily Mail you can read "A brief encounter: Model Bar Refaeli displays taut tum in black bra and iconic Calvin Klein underwear"